# Tab menu not working anymore after ajax request

Tags: jquery

When the page loads, everything works perfectly. However, after I make my ajax request which changes my tab menu content, it doesn't work properly anymore. What can I do to make it work at all times?

Here is my tab menu jquery code :

```
$('ul.stat-nav').each(function(){
    var $active, $content, $link = $(this).find('a');
    $active = $($link.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $link[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');

    $content = $($active[0].hash);

    $link.not($active).each(function () {
        $(this.hash).hide();
    });

    $(this).on('mouseover', 'a', function(e){
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();
        $active = $(this);
        $content = $(this.hash);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

My tab menu html code :

```
<div id="stats" class="right-stat">
    <ul class="stat-nav">
        <li class="stat-nav-tab"><a href="#W1">Basic</a></li>
        <li class="stat-nav-tab"><a href="#W2">Offensive</a></li>
        <li class="stat-nav-tab"><a href="#W3">Defensive</a></li>
        <li class="stat-nav-tab"><a href="#W4">Regeneration</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="wrap" id="W1"></div>
    <div class="wrap" id="W2"></div>
    <div class="wrap" id="W3"></div>
    <div class="wrap" id="W4"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the ajax request that changes it :

```
function calculate(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'calculator.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: { 'id': id },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#stats').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: With  $('#stats').html(data); you destroy you tabs. I don't know what the ajax result looks like. when it is the same dom as before you may only need to reinit you tabs

Comment: You should create  a function and call it after resetting html content. Another option, which is more dynamic, is using event delegation, `index` method helps you to find the target elements.

Comment: Thanks I did what you two said and now it works just fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are replacing the elements, JavaScript doesn't work like CSS, since the element doesn't exist, your listeners doesn't work. You should create a function and call it after resetting html content. Another option, which is more dynamic, is using event delegation, and `index` method helps you to find the target element.

```
var $stats = $('#stats').on('mouseenter', '.stat-nav a', function() {
   var index = $stats.find('.stat-nav a').index(this);
   var $target = $stats.find('.wrap').eq(index);
   // ...
});
```